# Rails: don't uglify HTML and CSS in test environment (using SLIM and Sass/Compass)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, assets

I'm actively validating the HTML and CSS in request specs. Sadly, the error messages are very long because the HTML and CSS is uglified/compressed in test env.

I tried to remove the `uglifier` gem from the Gemfile, but this didn't work out. Do I miss some configuration option here? I can't find any for `test.rb`...

**Update**

I found that setting `Slim::Engine.set_default_options pretty: true` solved the problem for the HTML output.

The CSS is still compressed on one line though, I tried stuff like adding `output_style = :nested` to `config/compass.css`, setting `Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :expanded` (raised an exception), add `config.sass.output_style = :nested` to `test.rb`, and setting `# config.assets.css_compressor = nil` also in `test.rb`. Didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting this in test.rb:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

In case you're using [SLIM](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) templating engine, set `pretty: true`:

```
Slim::Engine.set_default_options pretty: true
```

For more info see https://github.com/slim-template/slim#default-options.

Comment: I edited your answer so it is a complete answer to my case, so it can be accepted as the answer to this thread. Thank you! :)

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for CSS though, they are still on one line. :(

Comment: Now documentation recommends: `Slim::Engine.set_options pretty: true, sort_attrs: false`, replace `set_default_options` with `set_options`. But it works partially, the head block is fine, but code generated with simple_form is still one line.